# How do you compile from the command line?

Tags: incredibuild

According to their docs [here](http://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/BuildConsole.html), I should be able to build from the console like so:

```
BuildConsole mysolution.sln /build /cfg="Debug|Win32"
```

Where I have a Debug|Win32 build available, which I do.  If I load the solution in MSVS2010, I can build it.  However, when I try and build it from the command line or the system tray icon, it does nothing except output the message:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Build Acceleration Console 4.62 (build 1459)
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Xoreax Software Ltd. All rights reserved.
-----------------------------------------------------------------


Initializing...
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 cross tools.
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like although you are building "Debug|Win32", when you execute through the command line the Visual Studio 2010 x64 cross tools is loaded...
When you execute IncrediBuild through the BuildConsole command, it tries to set up your environment by executing the vcvars.bat file. In your scenario it seems that IncrediBuild is launching the vcvarsx86_amd64.bat instead of the vcvars32.bat

As far as I know, this issue was fixed in later versions of IncrediBuild.